# JPA EclipseLink - Não atualiza entidade

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse-link

Tenho um relação no JPA de Cliente 1 -> 0..* Empréstimos. Sendo assim tenho na classe cliente um conjunto List de emprestimo pra fazer o OneToMany. Acontece que quando adiciono um cliente ele atualiza normal a lista de clientes, entretanto quanto adiciono um emprestimo ele não atualiza a List emprestimos que tenho dentro de clientes. Apenas depois de reiniciar o tomcat ele atualiza a lista de Emprestimos.

Eu tenho que adicionar o emprestimo direto na List e dar um persiste no cliente?

No momento estou dando um persiste direto na classe empréstimo.

```
@Entity (name="cliente")
public class ClientePOJO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    @Transient
    private String nascimentoString;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date nascimento;
    private String telefoneResidencial;
    private String telefoneCelular;
    private String endereco;
    @Transient
    private String icon = "ui-icon-blank";


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="cliente")
    @JoinColumn(name="cliente_id")
    private List<EmprestimoPOJO> emprestimos;
```

Persistencia Cliente:

```
public static boolean adiciona(ClientePOJO novo){
        try{
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(novo);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Dados Gravados com Sucesso");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Erro ao gravar no banco de dados");
            return false;
        }
    }

public static List<ClienteBean> selectAll(){
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createQuery("select c from cliente c");
    return query.getResultList();

}
```

Persistencia Emprestimo:

```
public static boolean adiciona(EmprestimoPOJO novo){
        try{
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            //EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            //tx.begin();
            em.persist(novo);
            //tx.commit();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Dados Gravados com Sucesso");
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Erro ao gravar no banco de dados");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para ajudar, poste o método que usar para salvar.

Comment: Para salvar o Empréstimo, você deve ter uma `Transaction` aberta e realizar o `commit()`. Lembrando que você já vai passar o cliente em EmprestimoPOJO quando for salvar e que seu método listar não busca os empréstimos do cliente.

Comment: Tem como colocar a classe EmprestimoPOJO, ai também?

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente você deve ter o Empréstimo já cadastrado no banco para adicionar ao cliente.

Se você faz o cadastro na hora, junto com o cliente, deve dar um `persist()` no cadastro do Empréstimo e só então no cadastro do Cliente.

Se você salva o cliente primeiro, cadastra o Empréstimo e só depois associa o Empréstimo ao Cliente, então é um `merge()` no cadastro do Cliente.

Lembrando que deve comitar (com `commit()`) as suas transações ao final do processo antes de consultar novamente.

Comment: Estou fazendo na seguinte ordem. Cadastro o empréstimo. E depois, quando acesso outro menu, ele realizar um novo selectAll para renovar a lista de clientes q tenho.